# How can I take information from a database and auto-populate a PDF form?

Tags: java, php, forms, pdf, database-connection

I'm working with a group and we are writing software in Java We need to take information and store it in a database, and then use that database to auto-populate a PDF Form.

I've seen FDF Toolkit and PDFBox. FDF Toolkit doesn't seem like it'll do what we need. It just creates FDF Documents for online use, unless I've got that wrong. We need to save this information into the actual PDF inside our program.

PDFBox seems like the tool to do it, but I'm not sure exactly how to use it to just manipulate form data instead of the entire PDF.

I've also read that Form data is stored in an XML file and that we can manipulate the XML file and then just merge the data into a new form.

How can I take information from a database and auto-populate a PDF form? Is there another way to do it outside of writing our own program?

Answer (score 0):

You could use iText ! 
Here's the official examples page: [examples page](http://itextpdf.com/book/examples.php) and especially look at this example : [here](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=14) :
In that example they are showing the case of getting information about some countries from a database and outputing them to a pdf file! (pretty simple example though)
I think that either way you should write your own program to get to your purpose!
Hope it'll help!

Comment: I've looked at that. Can it merge data into an already existing PDF? Using FDF or XML? We need to take data and put it into a PDF form, not make an entirely new PDF document. I've read that PDF's store form data in XML format or FDF, but the FDFtoolkit doesn't look right for our needs.

Comment: Yes it is capable of reading PDF files and modifying them, and in the examples page there is something about FDF.